# OpenCV CvLevMarq( ) Class

Tags: opencv, levenberg-marquardt

I am new to OpenCV, I have to perform some camera calibration functions.
Can anybody tell me what are the uses of `CvLevMarq()` class in OpenCV and how to use it?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CvLevMarq()` function is implementation of Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear least squares algorithms used to iteratively finds a local minimum of a function that is expressed as the sum of squares of non-linear functions. It can be used to non-linearly estimate the essential matrix. OpenCV internally use the algorithm to find the camera intrinsic and extrinsic parameters from several views of a calibration pattern. You can check OpenCV as open source code to check how it is used in calibration. [Here](http://code.opencv.org/attachments/194/cvcalibration.cpp) is the link for the source code for calibration.

Comment: @isrish Can you tell me where is the source code for CvLevMarq() ??

Comment: This seems present on OpenCV up to 3.x but not in 4.x versions